# How to subtract a date object from another in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, countdown

I want to find how many days there are between two days. The next step is to find out how many hours there are between two days, but that's for later. I created a date object with today's date, and another date object with user inputs, then subtract the smaller date from the larger date. I think this is where I'm going wrong because it does not make sense to subtract a date from another date when both are naive, but it would make sense to subtract a datetime from another datetime (aware)?

I've verified the types of the objects using print(type(var)). Both created objects are of type date, and the result of subtracting is a timedelta object, as expected. Subtracting the date objects gives me the wrong number of days (400 something) when it should be 350 in my case.

````
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
days = list(range(1, 32))
months = list(range(1, 13))
today = date.today()

def inputInteger(message):
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an integer.")
            continue
        else:
            return userInput
            break


def inputMonth(message):
    while True:
        message = inputInteger(message)
        if message in months:
            return message
            break
        else:
            print("Please pick a value from 1-12")


def inputDay(message):
    while True:
        message = inputInteger(message)
        if int(message) in days:
            return message
            break
        else:
            print("Please pick a value from 1-31")


year = int(inputInteger('Enter a year'))
month = int(inputMonth('Enter a month (1-12)'))
day = int(inputDay('Enter a day (1-31)'))
# 2. add exception handling: leap years, leap seconds?, etc.
significantDate = date(year, month, day)
print("significant date:", significantDate, "of type", type(significantDate))
print("today:", today, "of type", type(today))
# 2. Tell me how many days are left until a certain date
if today > significantDate:
    delta = today - significantDate
    print("Days left:", delta.days)
else:
    print("entered less than")
    delta = significantDate - today
    print("Days left:", delta.days) 
    ```
````

Comment: What is your input from which you find its result is wrong?

Comment: I am putting in 12th of July, 2020. This should be 358 days, but i get 451 days.

Comment: it gives me 359, seems the code is no problem

Comment: Huh. Are you running Python 3.7?

Comment: yes. `Python 3.7.2`

Comment: Okay, I have no idea what's going on anymore :/ Win 10 here, running from PyCharm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196710/discussion-between-rddead-and-complicatedphenomenon).

Comment: @PyCharm, any problem with another date? It won't to this specific date, what is the output of your `today`?

Comment: today: 2019-07-19 of type <class 'datetime.date'>

today works fine

Comment: Another test case: 2019-07-19
Enter a year2019
Enter a month (1-12)11
Enter a day (1-31)12
significant date: 2019-11-12 of type <class 'datetime.date'>
today: 2019-07-19 of type <class 'datetime.date'>
entered less than
Days left: 116 so it does work for days within the same year.

Comment: 116 is same with mine and is right

Comment: So it's definitely some kind of overflow error specific to my platform. Narrowed down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

year = int(inputInteger('Enter a year'))
month = int(inputMonth('Enter a month (1-12)'))
day = int(inputDay('Enter a day (1-31)'))

significantDate =datetime.strptime(str(year) +str(month) + str(day), '%Y%m%d') 


today = datetime.now()
print(today)



dt = today - significantDate

print(dt.days)
```

Comment: This does convert both objects to datetime objects instead of just date objects, but I still get a bad result :(

Comment: Yep. 2019-07-22
Enter a year2020
Enter a month (1-12)10
Enter a day (1-31)12
significant date: 2020-10-12 of type <class 'datetime.date'>
today: 2019-07-22 of type <class 'datetime.date'>
Days left: 448